# How to adding Postgis to the running Postgresql container

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, postgis, postgis-installation

How to adding Postgis to the running Postgresql Docker Container. I can't delete postgresql. Because it has data and tables. I want to integrate Postgis'i without deleting tables and data. How can I do that?

```
psql --version ;
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1)
```

Comment: `apt-get install` the software?

Comment: not sure if you can do it , but there is postgis container https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/ on docker hub

Comment: You will routinely need to delete and recreate the database container (for example, to take updates in the underlying database engine); if you're storing data outside the container in a volume then it won't be lost when this happens.